How do I texture an oval connected to a square plane?
Needs to seamlessly be joined together as I need to add a tile texture, I'm wondering if this is even possible. I know I can just connect a cylinder and square plane and join them to make one merged plane, but adding textures in shading is difficult since they don't perfectly align, are different thicknesses, etc.


I know how to make the plane, sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm having an issue when it comes to adding shading textures.


Hello, what object are you trying to achieve exactly?

@moonboots a plane if possible

do you have a picture of the object? If you want a 3D object it would help

for the texture, it looks like you need to unwrap again


Add a circle.
Add a plane.
Move the circle( G ) and scale it appropriately( S ). Snapping functionality might be useful to scale it in a precise way. For example, you could place the 3d cursor at one point( Shift  +  S ), then select all geometry with one vert selected last so it's active and then when you scale it constrained to some axis, you can snap that vert to a corner of the plane so the circle stretches from the 3d cursor to the active vert that snaps to the corner of the plane. You would use 3d Cursor as transform pivot and set snapping settings to use Active as Snap Base:




Join the plane with the circle(now an oval) with  Ctrl  +  J  in object mode

Select the geometry you want to make a face out of and hit  F  to make a face between the part of the oval and the plane.  Ctrl +clicking to select shortest path might be useful to select needed verts of the oval.

Fill the oval by selecting all its verts and hitting  F  as well.



This is pretty basic modelling so I would highly recommend finding some course of video tutorials for modelling on YouTube or elsewhere online. It would answer a lot of questions all at once.
Edit:
There is nothing unusual about texturing it. It can be done multiple ways including:

UV mapping. Select the geometry in edit mode and Unwrap UV's( U ) using any of appropriate algorithms.


They will all work almost identically with such a simple geometry. The aim is to make a UV map:

You can then shade it the same way as you would anything else:


Using other coordinates like Object, or Generated for the texture:


